# Create Nest query with both HasChild and Query operators

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST with ElasticSearch in C#. I have an existing piece of code, that takes a QueryDescriptor type, and returns a BaseQuery.

The method is called a little like so :

```
...
.Query(
    queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor
        .Filtered(
            filteredQueryDescriptor => filteredQueryDescriptor
                .Query(queryString => searchParameters.SearchTree.ToElasticSearch(queryString))
                .Filter(filterDescriptor => searchParameters.SearchTree.ToElasticSearchFilter(filterDescriptor))
        )
)
...
```

The method "ToElasticSearch" looks a little like the following :

```
...
public override BaseQuery ToElasticSearch(QueryDescriptor<DomainProfile> queryDescriptor)
{
    return queryDescriptor.DoSomething
}
...
```

Now inside my ToElasticSearch method. I would like to return a BaseQuery that looks a bit like the following.

```
return queryDescriptor
.HasChild<ChildProfile>(
    child => child.Query(
        query => query.QueryString(
            queryStringDescriptor =>
                queryStringDescriptor.OnFieldsWithBoost(
                    boost => boost
                        .Add(profile => profile.Notes, 5)
                    )
                    .Query(QueryString.PrepareForSearch(SearchText))
                    .Operator(Operator.and)
                    .AutoGeneratePhraseQueries(true)
                    .PhraseSlop(0)
            )
        )
)
    ||
    queryDescriptor.QueryString(
        queryStringDescriptor =>
            queryStringDescriptor
                .OnFieldsWithBoost(
                    boost => boost
                        .Add(profile => profile.PersonalDetail.Email, 7)
                )
                .Query(QueryString.PrepareForSearch(SearchText))
                .Operator(Operator.and)
                .AutoGeneratePhraseQueries(true)
                .PhraseSlop(0)
        );
```

If it looks messy, that's because it is. Obviously the OR part is not right. I just did that to get things going for now (Or will it work? I don't think the Boost portion will work at all correct, but feel free to set me straight on that).

It seems like given a QueryDescriptor, I am unable to do both a query on the main search object, AND a child in the same query. It seems to be either or as both queries return a BaseQuery which I am unsure how to "tack on" if you will.

Comment: You can totally OR two or more queries like this with `||`. Do you still have issues with this?

Comment: Hi Martijn. Somewhat yes. This does work, but take my example. And set boost on Notes to 999, and boost on Email to 1. Check in which order results are returned. Then reverse the boost so Email has 999 and Notes has 1. And the result order is the same. It seems to apply boost to each query, and then at the very last step merge them together.